# Delphi ReadProcessMemory Problem

Tags: delphi

Its reading the first 3 address's right  and the last one wrong...Ignore the rubbish code I'm noob I just can't figure out why the 4th address no matter what even if i use the same address as one of the others returns the wrong value...

```
procedure ReadFirstCard(Address: Integer);
var
Handle,i,a,b,c : Integer;
begin
GetWindowThreadProcessId(FindWindow(nil, PAnsiChar(Client)), @ProcessId);
Handle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, ProcessId);
ReadProcessMemory(Handle, Ptr(Address), @NewValue, Data, CardRead);
CloseHandle(Handle);
end;

procedure ReadFirstCardSuit(Address2: Integer);
var
Handle,i,a,b,c : Integer;
begin
GetWindowThreadProcessId(FindWindow(nil, PAnsiChar(Client)), @ProcessId);
Handle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, ProcessId);
ReadProcessMemory(Handle, Ptr(Address2), @NewValue2, Data2, CardRead2);
CloseHandle(Handle);
end;

procedure ReadSecondCard(Address3: Integer);
var
Handle,i,a,b,c : Integer;
begin
GetWindowThreadProcessId(FindWindow(nil, PAnsiChar(Client)), @ProcessId);
Handle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, ProcessId);
ReadProcessMemory(Handle, Ptr(Address3), @NewValue3, Data3, CardRead3);
CloseHandle(Handle);
end;

procedure ReadSecondCardSuit(Address4: Integer);
var
Handle,i,a,b,c : Integer;
begin
GetWindowThreadProcessId(FindWindow(nil, PAnsiChar(Client)), @ProcessId);
Handle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, ProcessId);
ReadProcessMemory(Handle, Ptr(Address4), @NewValue4, Data4, CardRead4);
CloseHandle(Handle);
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the only thing different about the fourth function is that it uses `Data4` for the size instead of `Data1` through `Data3`, it seems that `Data4` must not have the correct value for the number of bytes to copy from the target process. Make sure `NewValue4` is big enough to receive the entire result, too.

You're not checking the return values of any of those API functions, so if they're failing, you'd never know it. Make sure that `OpenProcess` returns a valid handle, and make sure `ReadProcessMemory` returns non-zero. If they don't, call `GetLastError` to find out why.

Comment: if so, then either accept Rob's answer or add your own answer.